# Is Rails framework needed to deploy website written in Rails on server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Do I have to install `rails framework` to deploy a website written in rails on server ?

I am at online website written in rails and I don't know how this website was deployed. When I write `rails -v` it tells me `rails isn't installed`. I also tried to run `rvm -v` and `rbenv -v` but I get the same response, `not installed`

Comment: Your question is too broad. What kind of tool you use for deploy?

Comment: What u mean by 'too broad'?

Comment: i updated the question.

Comment: in which server are you deploying? I mean hosting provider.

Comment: Where you want to deploy this ? Or you just want to run code on your local machine. Also which environment you are using ubuntu / mac / window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploying rails application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778078/deploying-rails-application)

Comment: The website is deployed, and i want to make edits on it, So i was searching for rails on it. The website is deployed at ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I think rvm is not installed properly run this command

```
source /home/.....(username)/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```